# All windows showing fuzzy shadowing after waking from suspend

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, suspend

After waking my computer up from suspend, I was confronted with this:

[image: appearance after first wake from suspend]

It is reproducible, however the second time, it looked slightly different:

[image]

Notice the strange edges of all open windows, which seem to be showing the receptive area of the windows (perhaps the part that measures how close they are to other windows for snapping into place?)

Has anyone seen this before and is it a known issue, with a solution?

I haven't been able to find this problem explained anywhere else - perhaps because I don't know what to search for.

This machine has a newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 running on an Intel 6850k with an Nvidia graphics card using the driver 375 (installed via ppa).

Comment: Yep, seems to be the same problem that is described in that link. There are other solutions suggested in that thread, and the information is better summarised. I did actually post this question a day earlier though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found [this issue mentioned on an Nvidia forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/990898/linux/suspend-corrupts-window-manager-after-upgrade-to-378-09/2), and it seems to be related to the latest drivers, although the ones mentioned in the forum are slightly newer than my own. I have driver 375 and the issue is reported under 378.

It seems to be an issue involving **compiz**, and so simply killing (and presumably restarting) the process works.
A [workaround solution](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/990898/linux/suspend-corrupts-window-manager-after-upgrade-to-378-09/2#comment_5111693) posted by one user is to kill the process in a script that runs after the system wakes up:

```
kill $(ps -C compiz -o pid=)
```

I tried this during a session, by finding and killing the process:

```
~$ ps -C compiz
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
   4158 ?        00:00:11 compiz

~$ kill 4158
```

This leads to a few moments of weirdness, before **compiz** restarts - then everything is fine once again. As this is a reported bug, I would expect it to be fixed in the next driver release from Nvidia.

Comment: had an issue with this too,  this solution seems to work, Thanks

Comment: Check out the bug report here too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1675334

Comment: Reverting to the NVidia 340.102 proprietary driver is an acceptable workaround for me until the bug is fixed in a later driver. The primary bug is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158 so people can subscribe to that be notified of progress in fixing it.